# SimpleDateFormat and locale based format string

Tags: java, date, locale, simpledateformat

I'm trying to format a date in Java in different ways based on the given locale. For instance I want English users to see "Nov 1, 2009" (formatted by "MMM d, yyyy") and Norwegian users to see "1. nov. 2009" ("d. MMM. yyyy").

The month part works OK if I add the locale to the SimpleDateFormat constructor, but what about the rest?

I was hoping I could add format strings paired with locales to SimpleDateFormat, but I can't find any way to do this. Is it possible or do I need to let my code check the locale and add the corresponding format string?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use [DateFormat.getDateInstance(int style, Locale locale)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance(int,%20java.util.Locale)) instead of creating your own patterns with `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Thanks, this works OK. I went for DateFormat.LONG which suits my needs the best.

BTW, Norwegian locale and DateFormat.MEDIUM is crap(!)

Comment: You are right, the strange MEDIUM pattern for Norwegian never occured to me. The weekday is also missing in the FULL format, as opposed to most other locales.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome classes of `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Comment: I agree with @fiskeben. MEDIUM returns weird format ex: for `en_NZ` it returns `2/02/2020`

Answer (score 97):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
String formatted = dateFormat.format(the_date_you_want_here);
```

Answer (score 35):

Use the **style + locale**: *DateFormat.getDateInstance(int style, Locale locale)*

Check  http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html

Run the following example to see the differences:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DateFormatDemoSO {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int style = DateFormat.MEDIUM;
    //Also try with style = DateFormat.FULL and DateFormat.SHORT
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat df;
    df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(style, Locale.UK);
    System.out.println("United Kingdom: " + df.format(date));
    df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(style, Locale.US);
    System.out.println("USA: " + df.format(date));   
    df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(style, Locale.FRANCE);
    System.out.println("France: " + df.format(date));
    df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(style, Locale.ITALY);
    System.out.println("Italy: " + df.format(date));
    df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(style, Locale.JAPAN);
    System.out.println("Japan: " + df.format(date));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
United Kingdom: 25-Sep-2017
USA: Sep 25, 2017
France: 25 sept. 2017
Italy: 25-set-2017
Japan: 2017/09/25
```

Comment: Don't forget the `DateFormat.LONG` and `DateFormat.DEFAULT` styles!

Comment: Adding the output of your code would have been more complete

Comment: Right idea to specify style & locale. But the classes used are now outmoded. The troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 21):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now().format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM )
                     .withLocale( new Locale( "no" , "NO" ) )
)
```

The troublesome classes of `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

## `DateTimeFormatter`

Use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) to generate strings representing only the date-portion or the time-portion.

The [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) class can automatically [localize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization).

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( l );
String output = ld.format( f );
```

Going the other direction, you can parse a localized string.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
```

Note that the locale and time zone are completely orthogonal issues. You can have a Montréal moment presented in Japanese language or an Auckland New Zealand moment presented in Hindi language.

Another example: Change `6 junio 2012` (Spanish) to `2012-06-06` (standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format). The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default for parsing/generating strings.

```
String input = "6 junio 2012";
Locale l = new Locale ( "es" , "ES" );
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "d MMMM uuuu" , l );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse ( input , f );
String output = ld.toString();  // 2012-06-06.
```

### Peruse formats

Here is some example code for perusing the results of multiple formats in multiple locales, automatically localized.

An [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) is an implementation of [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), highly optimized for both low memory usage and fast execution speed when collecting [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) objects. So, `EnumSet.allOf( FormatStyle.class )` gives us a collection of all four of the [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) enum objects to loop. For more info, see [Oracle Tutorial on enum types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

```java
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 );

List < Locale > locales = new ArrayList <>( 3 );
locales.add( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
locales.add( new Locale( "no" , "NO" ) );
locales.add( Locale.US );

// Or use all locales (almost 800 of them, for about 120K text results).
// Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales(); // All known locales. Almost 800 of them.

for ( Locale locale : locales )
{
    System.out.println( "------|  LOCALE: " + locale + " — " + locale.getDisplayName() + "  |----------------------------------" + System.lineSeparator() );

    for ( FormatStyle style : EnumSet.allOf( FormatStyle.class ) )
    {
        DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( style ).withLocale( locale );
        String output = ld.format( f );
        System.out.println( output );
    }
    System.out.println( "" );
}
System.out.println( "« fin »" + System.lineSeparator() );
```

Output.

```
------|  LOCALE: fr_CA — French (Canada)  |----------------------------------

mardi 23 janvier 2018
23 janvier 2018
23 janv. 2018
18-01-23

------|  LOCALE: no_NO — Norwegian (Norway)  |----------------------------------

tirsdag 23. januar 2018
23. januar 2018
23. jan. 2018
23.01.2018

------|  LOCALE: en_US — English (United States)  |----------------------------------

Tuesday, January 23, 2018
January 23, 2018
Jan 23, 2018
1/23/18

« fin »
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the java.time answer I was looking for 

Answer (score 9):

Localization of date string:

Based on redsonic's post:

```
private String localizeDate(String inputdate, Locale locale) { 

    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatCN = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", locale);       
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");


    try {
        date = dateFormat.parse(inputdate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        log.warn("Input date was not correct. Can not localize it.");
        return inputdate;
    }
    return dateFormatCN.format(date);
}

String localizedDate = localizeDate("05-Sep-2013", new Locale("zh","CN"));
```

will be like 05-九月-2013

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!
Here I added a suggestion actually confused with the date format name ("dateFormatCN" and "dateFormat") will took almost 2 hrs, so i just added it for reference this is for **"dateFormat" is input date format** & **"dateFormatCN" is output date format**.

Answer (score 5):

This will display the date according to user's **current locale**:

To return date and time:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;    
import java.util.Date;

Date date = new Date();
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
String myDate = df.format(date);
```

Dec 31, 1969 7:00:02 PM

To return date only, use:

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance()
```

Dec 31, 1969

Answer (score 2):

**Java 8 Style for a given date**

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.of(1982, Month.AUGUST, 31);
System.out.println(today.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM).withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)));
System.out.println(today.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM).withLocale(Locale.FRENCH)));
System.out.println(today.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM).withLocale(Locale.JAPANESE)));
```

Comment: I believe [I covered this kind of solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40920186/642706) a year ago.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps someone. Please find in the below code which accepts Locale instance and returns the locale specific date format/pattern.

```
public static String getLocaleDatePattern(Locale locale) {
    // Validating if Locale instance is null
    if (locale == null || locale.getLanguage() == null) {
        return "MM/dd/yyyy";
    }
    // Fetching the locale specific date pattern
    String localeDatePattern = ((SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance(
            DateFormat.SHORT, locale)).toPattern();
    // Validating if locale type is having language code for Chinese and country
    // code for (Hong Kong) with Date Format as - yy'?'M'?'d'?'
    if (locale.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("zh_hk")) {
        // Expected application Date Format for Chinese (Hong Kong) locale type
        return "yyyy'MM'dd";
    }
    // Replacing all d|m|y OR Gy with dd|MM|yyyy as per the locale date pattern
    localeDatePattern = localeDatePattern.replaceAll("d{1,2}", "dd")
            .replaceAll("M{1,2}", "MM")
            .replaceAll("y{1,4}|Gy", "yyyy");
    // Replacing all blank spaces in the locale date pattern
    localeDatePattern = localeDatePattern.replace(" ", "");
    // Validating the date pattern length to remove any extract characters
    if (localeDatePattern.length() > 10) {
        // Keeping the standard length as expected by the application
        localeDatePattern = localeDatePattern.substring(0, 10);
    }
    return localeDatePattern;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d, yyyy").format(date);
```

Answer (score -2):

## Java8

```
 import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;         
 myDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-YYYY",new Locale("ar")))
```

Comment: Using `ofPattern` with a locale argument will give you month name in the desired language, but not different formats as requested in the question. Using uppercase `YYYY` will give you incorrect and very surprising results in corner cases. Using Java 8 is a good idea.