# Parse a String to Date in Java

Tags: java, string, date, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse a string to a date, this is what I have:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zZ (zzzz)");
Date date = new Date();
try {
    date = sdf.parse(time);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the string to parse is this:

```
Sun Jul 15 2012 12:22:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)
```

I followed the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Pretty sure I've done everything by the book. But it is giving me `ParseException`.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 
"Sun Jul 15 2012 12:22:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)"
```

What am I doing wrong?  Patterns I Have tried:

```
EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz
EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zZ (zzzz)
```

Comment: I think it should be `"... zz (zzzz)`, you capitalized one `Z`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer the problem still remains unfortunately

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661325/simpledateformat-and-locale-based-format-string) it is :D
I think that one covers what you need :D

Comment: Where does the `time` String come from?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seem to be mixing the patterns for `z` and `Z`. If you ignore the `(FLE Daylight Time)`, since this is the same info as in `GMT+0300`, the problem becomes that `SimpleDateFormat` wants either `GMT +0300` or `GMT+03:00`. The last variant can be parsed like this:

```
String time = "Sun Jul 15 2012 12:22:00 GMT+03:00 (FLE Daylight Time)";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
Date date = sdf.parse(time);
```

**[EDIT]**
In light of the other posts about their time strings working, this is probably because your time string contains conflicting information or mixed formats.

Comment: You need to add the `:` to your time string for this to work.

Comment: are you sure since ... using : `EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz`, and when I print it out : ` Date date = new Date(); ` , and then show the format : `System.out.println(sdf.format(date));` , it prints : `Thu Jul 12 2012 10:47:09 EEST`

Comment: Actually I did this, and it worked ... `time = time.substring(0, 31) + ":" + time.substring(31);` . seems very weird, no easier way lol?

Comment: Like I said, it seems your `time` String is using mixed formats in an unfortunate way that causes trouble for `SimpleDateFormat`, so if you have any way to generate that in a more friendly pattern, that would certainly help.

Comment: Problem comes because of diff timezones GMT or EEET, so I just reduced it to only what I need. until minutes and seconds. `time = time.substring(0, 21);`

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

I should like to contribute the modern answer. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

First define a formatter for parsing:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter PARSER = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (", Locale.ROOT);
```

Then parse in this way:

```
    String time = "Sun Jul 15 2012 12:22:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)";
    
    TemporalAccessor parsed = PARSER.parse(time, new ParsePosition(0));
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.from(parsed);
    
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output is:

> 2012-07-15T12:22+03:00

I am not parsing your entire string, but enough to establish a point in time and an offset from GMT (or UTC). Java cannot parse the time zone name *FLE Daylight Time*. This is a Microsoft invention that Java does not know. So I parse up to the round bracket before *FLE* in order to validate this much of the string. To instruct the `DateTimeFormatter` that it needs not parse the entire string I use the overloaded `parse` method that takes a `ParsePosition` as second argument.

From Wikipedia:

> Sometimes, due to its use on Microsoft Windows, FLE Standard Time (for
> Finland, Lithuania, Estonia, or sometimes Finland, Latvia, Estonia) …
> are used to refer to Eastern European Time.

If you indispensably need a `Date` object, typically for a legacy API that you cannot afford to upgrade to java.time just now, convert like this:

```
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(dateTime.toInstant());
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

Output when run in Europe/Tallinn time zone:

> Sun Jul 15 12:22:00 EEST 2012

### What went wrong in your code?

Your `SimpleDateFormat` successfully parsed `GMT+03` into a “time zone” matching the small `z` in the format pattern string. It then tried to parse the remaining `00` into an offset to match the capital `Z`. Since an offset requires a sign, this failed.

> What am I doing wrong?

As others have said, you should not try to parse `GMT` into a time zone abbreviation. `GMT` *can* be used as a time zone abbreviation; but your time is not in GMT. So you don’t want that. It would only be misleading. Had you been successful, you would rather have risked an incorrect result because you had parsed a time zone that was incorrect for your purpose.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Eastern European Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_European_Time) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way..

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zZ (zzzz)").format(new Date()));
```

**Output i got:**

```
Thu Jul 12 2012 12:41:35 IST+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: It is using my own language, not english, jeez, `N Juuli 12 2012 10:19:35 EEST+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)`

Comment: use `SimpleDateFormat(String pattern, Locale.US)`

Comment: @Subs used locale, but still getting exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to print the date format string :

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zZ (zzzz)");
    Date date = new Date();
    try {
        //
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
        date = sdf.parse(time);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is using my language, wtf, I want it to use english. `N Juuli 12 2012 10:18 EEST+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)`

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems with locales, you can either set the default Locale for the whole application

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

or just use the english locale on your `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zZ (zzzz)", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

You can also use `Locale.US` or `Locale.UK`.