# Get Next Jsoup Element with Same Name Android

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm retreving elements in Android with Jsoup. I need to get the next eta element from this code. I'm not sure how to. I'm retreiving the xml from: http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx?key=201412abc85d49b2b83f907f9e329eaa&mapid=40380. Someone has brought up using elem.iterator(), but I'm not sure how to put this in my code (this is the website for it)http://www.jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#iterator()   My code is below.

TestStation.java

```
public class TestStation extends Activity {
String URL = "http://lapi.transitchicago.com/api/1.0/ttarrivals.aspx?key=201412abc85d49b2b83f907f9e329eaa&mapid=40380";
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_station);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 



Document doc = null;

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
TextView tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv4);
TextView tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv5);

try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; de-de) AppleWebKit/523.10.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.4 Safari/523.10").get();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    Iterator<Element> iterator = elem.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())
{ Element div = iterator.next();

Elements arrT = div.select("arrT");
Elements prdt = div.select("prdt");
Elements staNm = div.select("staNm");
String StaNm = staNm.text();
tv1.setText(String.valueOf (StaNm));


while(iterator.hasNext())
{ Element div1 = iterator.next();

Elements arrT1 = div1.select("arrT");
Elements prdt1 = div1.select("prdt");
Elements staNm1 = div1.select("staNm");
String StaNm1 = staNm1.text();
tv2.setText(String.valueOf (StaNm1));



try {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date1 = sdf.parse(arrT.text());
    Date date2 = sdf.parse(prdt.text());
    Date date3 = sdf.parse(arrT1.text());
    Date date4 = sdf.parse(prdt1.text());

    long dateDiff = (date1.getTime() - date2.getTime())>0 ? (date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) :(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    long dateDiff1 = (date3.getTime() - date4.getTime())>0 ? (date3.getTime() - date4.getTime()) :(date4.getTime() - date3.getTime());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:00");
    String dateDif = sdf1.format(dateDiff);
    String dateDif1 = sdf1.format(dateDiff1);
    tv.setText(String.valueOf (dateDif));
    tv3.setText(String.valueOf (dateDif1));


    }

catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();



 }

}
}
}
```

I'm now getting LogCat errors, and it says that it has stopped working:

```
09-26 20:34:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(22691): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dev.chicagotraintracker/com.dev.chicagotraintracker.TestStation}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 20:34:50.456: E/AndroidRuntime(22691):    at com.dev.chicagotraintracker.TestStation.onCreate(TestStation.java:57)
```

With my code, I get two elements, but they are the exact same. I get the same numbers for dateDiff and dateDiff1. How can I get the next eta element with the same name? Thank you for your help.

Comment: the code i see, doesn't make sense at all. Consider rephrasing your question.

Comment: My substract, do you mean the mathematical substraction like: <arrT>20130921 17:32:24</arrT> - <prdt>20130921 17:16:24</prdt>? You have multiple entries of <eta>, each containing arrT and prdt, Do you wanna do it for each entry?

Comment: Yeah, I would want to subtract mathamatically just the time part of 17:32:24 and 17:16:24. I would want to do it for each entry.

Comment: @Alécio With the `while(iterator.hasNext())`, will that still run the code even if there isn't a next element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understood correctly, this might help you:

```
Elements elem = doc.select("eta");
Iterator<Element> iterator = elem.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Element etaElement = iterator.next();
    Element arrT = etaElement.select("arrT");    
    Element prdt = etaElement.select("prdt");
    //  1. parse the arrT value
    //  2. parse the prdt value
    //  3. subtract them.
}
```

Like this you will be able to individually handle each entry. Note the the `div.select` is being used for each `eta` element and not from the whole document, as your code was doing.

Comment: This helps, but how can I physically subtract them? What should I put in my code to subtract the two?

Comment: It depends of the type, you will have to do some work with SimpleDateFormat define the pattern, so it can parse the text into a Date object, and with a Date object you can mathematically subtract the values...It's not complicated, just takes few lines...see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446420/parse-string-to-date-java

Comment: How can I advance to the next eta element? I have the code again, and have changed all the variables, but it displays the same number. @Hi-Tech Android KitKat

Comment: How can I advance to the next eta element? I have the code again, and have changed all the variables, but it displays the same number. @Alecio

Comment: @hichris123 try to use the elem.iterator()  (elem => Elements) then you can run the loop over the iterator. http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#iterator()

Comment: If you would, could I have some code for that? I would love it. @Alecio

Comment: well i thought this was clear enough, but anyway, with an Iterator object in hands you can iterate over a collection of elements, in your case, you will be iterating over a collection of objects representing "eta". For some reference on using Iterators in your code, please refer to: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: I have this on the second part, but it doesn't work. `for (Iterator<Element> j = elem.iterator(); j.hasNext(); );;
        Elements elem1 = doc.select("eta");`. Can I have some help?

Comment: if "elem" is a <eta> element...then you can't do the doc.select(eta) on it..of course, so you have to do the: div.select("arrT"); for each element in the iterator.

Comment: I'll post it to the origional question.

Comment: the code you've posted, made even more confused..try to follow the logic you wrote. Anyway, I updated the answer on how to use the Iterator in this case.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. However, it displays a logcat error. It's posted above.

Comment: what's on the line 57 (TestStation.java:57)? Sorry, but i won't be able to help you step by step like this with minor questions. I believe you can take it from here.

Comment: `Iterator<Element> iterator = elem.iterator();` is on line 57.

Comment: then...elem is null. Meaning that doc.select("eta") failed to retrieve the "eta"...."doc" is supposed to be the whole document. Unless if you're doing something different.

Comment: Hey, just wondering, will the when statment still execute the code if there is no next Element? And if I were to want to see if those strings equaled something, would those strings be empty?