# JSoup parsing: get next element

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I have searched around I cannot find a way to do this. I have a group of elements. I select one element from this group. How could I find the next element after this selected element?

Comment: This might help you, it's not quite what you're asking, but similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938083/get-next-jsoup-element-with-same-name-android

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the method `nextElementSibling()`.

Example:

```
<body>
    <p>First in family!</p>
    <p>Second in family!</p>
    <p>Third in family!</p>
</body>
```

Jsoup:

```
Element firstParagraph = doc.select("p:eq(0)").first();
Element secondParagraph = firstParagraph.nextElementSibling();

System.out.println(firstParagraph.text() + " " + secondParagraph.text());
```

> Output: First in family! Second in family!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am getting a null pointer exception when I call .nextElementSibling

Comment: What is your stacktrace? I hadn't run the code when I posted the answer, but when I tried it now it works perfectly, except that you might want to add .text() to just get the text instead of the complete <p>-tag!

Comment: How to get next in selector syntax?