# Converting String to Date in Java and sort based on current date.

Tags: java, parsing, date

This Question might have been answered here quite often but I could not find an answer specific to my question, I as well tried to go through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html and infer something but to no avail.

I have a simple string date `YYYY-MM-DD` and I want to convert it into corresponding Date type like `DD-MM-YYYY` and save it in a database under a date type column. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem with `order by`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String to Date in Different Format in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882420/string-to-date-in-different-format-in-java)

Comment: Yes the order by is the problem, I am not interested in the time stamp however the Date is important and the way it is presented that is DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446420/parse-string-to-date-java

Comment: Yes I already mentioned that it has been answered, but I want a specific solution and I want to understand how it works.

Comment: why are you bothering to convert it to a string *before* sorting?  That's a lot more work than sorting by the long value and then converting the dates to your format.

Comment: I am converting a string to Date not the other way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

```
String DateStr="2012-12-12";
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(DateStr); 

java.sql.Date d1 = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());
```

Now if you are using PreparedStatement then

```
pt.setDate(1,d1);
```

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for leaving a comment.Sorry i didnt find any mistake.

Comment: @BalusC sorry for the mistake.Just compiled and pasted it here

Comment: Finally the right answer covering all aspects stated in the question! I removed the downvote. Please interpret that undeserved sympathy upvote as my upvote.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for removing the downvote but what is mean by **Please interpret that undeserved sympathy upvote as my upvote**

Comment: When your answer was downvoted to -1, some nitwit counteracted it by upvoting it back to 0 while your answer was still wrong. This is not right and it's called a "sympathy upvote".

Comment: @BalusC I think a user just upvoted all the answers,every ones answer changed from -1 to 0.well it would have been nice if you just pointed the mistake before downvoting.Well thanks again now

Comment: If a mistake is obvious by simply running the code in answer yourself, I always downvote (and also always remove downvote once fixed).

Comment: Its actually a good practice, because so many answers mislead and the best should get filtered.

Answer (score 0):

Use a TreeMap instead of HashMap. As Date already implements Comparable, it will be sorted automatically on insertion.

```
Map<Date, ArrayList> m = new TreeMap<Date, ArrayList>();
```

Alternatively, if you have an existing HashMap and want to create a TreeMap based on it, pass it to the constructor:

```
Map<Date, ArrayList> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Date, ArrayList>(m);
```

Comment: Hey sorting is a different issue, how about sorting in Ascending order based on current date? I will have to use a comparator I think.

Comment: Yes use your own comparator but date already implements comparator

Comment: Am on it mate :) Thanks a lot for guidance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you scenario is to convert a string to date then save it to your DB, then i think that you don't have to convert the string to date, just pass the date string with a proper format(this depends on your DB vendor) to your insert method, and it will be saved successfully into your DB.

Comment: Its a lightweight database, called as SQlite. Not so robust. Because I need calculations based on this date, it would be apt to store it in Date format.

Answer (score 0):

When you have strings like "10-07-2015"  and  "01-08-2017" in your database and use ORDER BY the printed result will be in the sequence of  "01-08-2017" , "10-07-2015" .

Same thing happens when you put the string dates into a Treemap, because both Treemap and ORDER BY identify the input as numbers, not as dates.

When you use a different date format, like "yyyy-MM-dd", here the print output is in the correct sequence, "2015-07-10" , 2017-08-01". But it is in the wrong date format.

One workaround solution would be to convert dates into longs before adding them to the database :

```
Date date_1 = Mon Jul 10 16:06:22 BRT 2015;
Date date_2 = Fri Aug 01 14:04:23 BRT 2017;

Long long_Date_1 = date_1.getTime();    // (prints something like 1502133102260)
Long long_Date_2 = date_2.getTime();    // (prints something like 1233335544343)
```

When you put these longs into the database, you can retrieve them sorted from the database and easily convert them into date string with the desired format:

```
Date date_1 = new Date ( long_Date_1 );
Date date_2 = new Date ( long_Date_2 );

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

formatter.format(date_1));  // prints "10-07-2015" 
formatter.format(date_2));  // prints  "01-08-2017"
```