# Convert string to date in android the best way

Tags: java, android, string, datetime

What is the best way and how to convert this string **"2015-07-18T13:32:56.971-0400"** to date and converting to **user's phone's local timezone** in android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse a String to Date in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446420/parse-a-string-to-date-in-java)

Comment: duplicate of [How to get TimeZone from android mobile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672597/how-to-get-timezone-from-android-mobile) for 2nd question.

Comment: My string is a bit different and my aim to display this on user's local date time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I listed the *duplicate* link because you're asking how to parse a date string. That has been answered a gazillion times.

The other link shows that the user's phone's local timezone in android **is** the default timezone of the JVM, so you don't have to do **any** conversion.

To see for yourself, run the following code *in any JVM* (Android, PC, Mac, Linux, ...):

```
String input = "2015-07-18T13:32:56.971-0400";

Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").parse(input);
String output = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS a").format(date);
System.out.println(input + "  ->  " + output);
```

If you're in Los Angeles, CA, USA, you get this:

```
2015-07-18T13:32:56.971-0400  ->  07/18/2015 10:32:56.971 AM
```

Note that 13:32 was adjusted to 10:32 AM (10:32).

Comment: Thank you this is what i asked for :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use these to get the time and date

```
public String getCurrentDate(){
    Time dtNow = new Time();
    dtNow.setToNow();
    return dtNow.format("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M");    // YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS
}

public String getCurrentTime(){
    Time dtNow = new Time();
    dtNow.setToNow();
    return dtNow.format("%H:%M");    // YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS
}
```

the first function will return time and the second function returns date

Comment: its basically getting the time and date which is what you want to get in the real sense.