# Android DateFormat. Custom style (dd/MM/yyyy) in different locales

Tags: android, date

I have to represent date in different locales.
Some locale standards should show as `dd/MM/yyyy`, some  - `MM/dd/yyyy`.
I know that I can use `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT)` to achieve result **like I want**, but not completely.

`DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT)` will formate date similar to `dd/MM/yy`, while I need `dd/MM/yyyy` (`YEAR` to show like `2016`, not like `16`).

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

> getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT)

returns shorter date

> getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG)

returns longer format .

```
SHORT is completely numeric, such as 12.13.52 or 3:30pm
LONG is longer, such as January 12, 1952 or 3:30:32pm
```

You can also set the time zone on the format if you wish. If you want even more control over the format or parsing, (or want to give your users more control), you can try casting the **[DateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html)** you get from the factory methods to a **[SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)**. This will work for the majority of countries; just remember to put it in a try block in case you encounter an unusual one.

For more Reference

1. **[SimpleDateFormat and locale based format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661325/simpledateformat-and-locale-based-format-string)**

Comment: Have you read the question? `DateFormat.LONG` doesn't give what I need. i know how it works.

Comment: @VladMatvienko sorry , you can use `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: I know how to use `SimpleDateFormat` as well. But it doesn't give what I want. What I want is the date `19/12/2016` for US Locale to be formatted as `12/19/2016`, according to US date rules

Comment: @VladMatvienko serious case .

Comment: Yes, and I thought that it is common case, and common problem, but it themes that there is no standard solution so far

Comment: @VladMatvienko indeed . seems like common issue .whats your java version ?

Comment: Unfortunately it is only Java 7. I can't use Java 8 since have to legacy-support Android 2.3+

Comment: No so far. Discussing with the managers for an option to use `getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT)`. I don't think that there is any better solution for me