# Local DateTime Format with suffix

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, culture

I'm currently trying to display a datetime in the format of the local culture of the user.

As an example, an user from the US will see a date as `20 June 2020 05.50 PM` where as an user from germany will see the date as `20 Juni 2020, 17:50`.

My issue is, that e.g for the german case, I'd like to have a `Uhr` added at the end, so it will be `20 Juni 2020, 17:50 Uhr` as explained [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377410/use-different-time-formats-according-to-language).

Is there any way to achieve that in .NET as well? In theory I could just keep checking the culture and add `Uhr` if it's a german one, but I assume that there are other cultures as well with a similar suffix.

Comment: Did you try adding `tt` to your format string? That should include the am/pm designator which it sounds like may the uhr as well

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Did you mean ```t``` (or ```T```)? That adds the am/pm as you said but sadly only displays the time for the german culture.

Comment: Yah I just tried it and it didn't work. You could override the Am/pm designator for the culture to include the Uhr and then use the standard format strings... but you'd have to set it per culture it looks like

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#ttSpecifier