# Android: How to display time in 12-hour format for US and 24-format for UK?

Tags: android, time

Currently I'm using `new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.getDefault())` to display time in my app. It always shows time like `12:00 AM` either the device language is set to English (US) or English (UK).
I would like to change this behaviour and display time in 24-h format for devices which language is set to English (UK). Is there a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DateFormat.getDateInstance(int style, Locale locale)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance(int,%20java.util.Locale))

Comment: Also you can visit similar problem here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661325/simpledateformat-and-locale-based-format-string

Answer (score 0):

Use this [Simple and understandable :) ] :

```java
final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String locale = Locale.getDefault().toString();

        if (locale.equals("en_US")) {

            SimpleDateFormat US = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
            String us = US.format(calendar.getTime());
            Log.i ("US - Time is : ",us);

        } else if (locale.equals("en_GB")) {

            SimpleDateFormat UK = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
            String uk = UK.format(calendar.getTime());
            Log.i ("UK - Time is : ",uk);

        } else {

            Log.i("Your Location ",locale);

        }}
```

I've created a **conditions** that can **change** the **time** according to the location [**Locale**] !
hope to be useful.

Good luck.

Comment: Though this way does what I want, I would avoid using such comparisons with raw string constants since there could be other locales (not only US and UK) and I'd like to display dates considering rules for each locale. Sorry, I should have mentioned this in my question.