# Format Date with readable type for specific Locale / Country

Tags: java, android, kotlin, time, simpledateformat

In project there is few usage of DateUtils.formatDateTime() which is ignoring custom Locale.

So I want to replace it somehow with custom locale and readable type for specific Locale.

**What it means:**

```
 * en: OldFormatter=Arrive Mar 3, 2073 9:15 AM NewFormatter=Arrive Mar 3, 2073 9:15 AM
 * pl: OldFormatter=przybycie: 3.03.2073 09:15 NewFormatter=przybycie: mar 3, 2073 9:15 AM
 * de: OldFormatter=Ankunft: 3. März 2073 09:15 NewFormatter=Ankunft: Mär 3, 2073 9:15 AM
```

Like You can see OldFormatter have different schema depends on the Locale / Country.

NewFormatter using SimpleDateFormat ( which supporting custom Locale usage) but every Locale / Country has the same format.

How can I use custom Locale but also keep format support depends on Locale / Country ?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: @OleV.V.Thanks for Your suggestion. Could You help me how to format date with results like in example OldFormatter using  ThreeTenABP ? I'm still getting date with the same pattern not localised by Locale. The problem for me is that I need to keep old Date format in application which is for example formatted by: DateUtils.formatDateTime(context, arrivalTime, FORMAT_SHORT_TIME);  or DateUtils.formatDateTime(context, arrivalTime, FORMAT_SHORT_TIME) + ", " + DateUtils.formatDateTime(context, arrivalTime, FORMAT_DAY_AND_SHORT_MONTH); but DateUtils.formatDateTime not supporting custom Locale

Comment: Did you try if you could adopt [this answer by Basil Bourque to the linked original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40920186/5772882)?

Comment: I had expected something like `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM, FormatStyle.SHORT)` to give you what you asked for. However on my Java 11 for different locales I get: en: `Mar 3, 2073, 9:15 AM`
pl: `3 mar 2073, 09:15`
de: `03.03.2073, 09:15`. The first is what you asked for, the other two not exactly. But they all reflect what Unicode in Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR) has registered as appropriate formats for those locales, so I would suggest that you’re well off relying on them. You may also see if you get slightly different (better?) results on Android.

Comment: @OleV.V.Thanks a lot. I have one more question to be sure. If I will use custom date pattern every date will be formated to this pattern without any additional formatting depends on Locale ? Or there is a option to format pattern for example dd.MM.yyyy with results pl: 3 mar 2073 en: March 3 2073 ? Or this is possible using only predefined constants format like  FormatStyle.SHORT etc.

Comment: You are correct, it is either one or the other. Using a format pattern string and a locale will allow you to have `Mar`, in English, lowercase `mar` in Polish and `Mär` (or `Mrz`) in German, but will not allow you to change punctuation or switch between `mar`, `3` and `03`.