# How can I format day and month in the locale-correct order in Java?

Tags: java, localization, date-formatting

Is there a way to format a day and month (in compact form), but not year, in the locale-correct order in Java/Kotlin?  So for English it should be "Sep 20" but for Swedish "20 sep.".

For comparison, on Cocoa platforms, I can do the following (in Swift):

```swift
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "sv_SE")
formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMM d")
print(formatter.string(from: Date()))
```

This will correctly turn things around. Is there an equivalent thing to do with the Java SDKs? I've been trying various forms with both `DateTimeFormatter` and the older `SimpleTimeFormat` APIs, but no success.

**Notes:** Unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661325/simpledateformat-and-locale-based-format-string), I don't want the full medium format that includes the year.  I also don't want either `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d")`, since that gives the incorrect result in Swedish, or `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMM")`, since that gives the incorrect result in English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SimpleDateFormat and locale based format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661325/simpledateformat-and-locale-based-format-string)

Comment: @Mark No, that is including the year, i.e. a full date format

Comment: FYI, Java does offer the [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html) class to represent a month and day without a year. Unfortunately, the automatic localization features of *java.time* do not currently extend to this particular class, where we call `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, sorry. I know of no Java library that will automatically turn `"MMM d"` around into `20 sep.` for a locale that prefers the day of month before the month abbreviation.

You may try modifying the [answer by Rowi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56802254/642706) in this way:

```
DateTimeFormatter ft = 
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
    .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("sv-SE"))
;
```

However the result is:

> 20 sep. 2019

It includes the year, which you didn’t ask for.

An advanced solution would use the [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) class to build [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) objects.

```
DateTimeFormatterBuilder
.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
    FormatStyle.MEDIUM, 
    null, 
    IsoChronology.INSTANCE, 
    Locale.forLanguageTag("sv-SE")
)
```

This returns `d MMM y`. Modify this string to delete the `y` and the space before it. Note that in other languages the `y` may be `yy`, `yyyy` or `u` and may not come last in the string. Pass your modified format pattern string to `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`.

It may be shaky. Even if you look through the format pattern strings for all available locales, the next version of [CLDR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository) (where the strings come from) might still contain a surprise. But I think it’s the best we can do. If it were me, I’d consider throwing an exception in case I can detect that the string from `getLocalizedDateTimePattern` doesn’t look like one I know how to modify.

Comment: Thanks! This seems like the right answer, unfortunately. Getting the format string and modifying it does however feel kinda shaky...

Comment: Thanks! Superb suggestions, all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in Java using LocalDate:

```
LocalDate dt = LocalDate.parse("2019-09-20"); 
System.out.println(dt);   
DateTimeFormatter ft = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM", new Locale("sv","SE")); 
System.out.println(ft.format(dt));
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really address the question. It should be "20 sep." in Swedish but "Sep 20" in English, without me having to specify what the order is for each language.

Comment: @skagedal, With Locale (new Locale("sv","SE")) It will format to "20 sep" without Locale , It will format to "20 Sep"

Comment: @Rowi That still doesn't answer the question. It's about the order of day & month. With UK locale it should be 'month day', with Swedish it should be 'day month'

Answer (score 1):

You could get the `DateFormat`'s pattern and remove the year:

```kotlin
val locale: Locale
val datePattern = (DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale) as SimpleDateFormat).toPattern()
    .replace("y", "").trim { it < 'A' || it > 'z' }
```

Comment: Right, that is essentially the same type of solution as Basil wrote above, but using a different API. Thanks for contributing it!