# How to print month from sql date in different language (Spanish) in java?

Tags: java, sql, simpledateformat

I am able to print month in English with these lines of code
But how can i Print it in Spanish? I didn't find any Spanish in Locale of (Simple Date Format)

Comment: Timestamp a= null; (Getting this date from DB);
    DateFormat date=new Simple Date Format("MMM d, yyyy h:mm a");
    String b= date.format(a);

Comment: Ene
Feb
Mar
Abr
May
Jun
Jul
Ago
Sep
Oct
Nov
Dic

Comment: show your code!!

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `Month` and/or `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Thanks for showing your code. Please add it *in the question* so we have everything in one place, and so that you can format it into a readable format. Code tends to be unreadable when posted in comments.

Comment: In the linked original question I recommend the answers [by Basil Bourque]{https://stackoverflow.com/a/40920186/5772882) and [by Mircea Stanciu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46945783/5772882) using `DateTimeFormatter` from java.time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateFormat` and `java.util.Date` it uses are outdated. You should (if possible) use the more recent JSR-310 java date/time libraries and formatters that work with it like `DateTimeFormatter`. Below is an example code with the recent, **recommended** JSR-310 Java date/time library and the recent `DateTimeFormatter` using a Spanish (Spain) locale:

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy h:mm a", new Locale("es", "ES"));

String formattedDateTime = dateTimeFormatter.format(dateTime);
```

If you for whatever reason have to use the **old outdated libraries**, then you can use `SimpleDateFormat(String pattern, Locale locale)`. Below is an example code of usage of `DateFormat` with the Spanish (Spain) locale:

```
Date dateTime = new Date();

DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "MMM d, yyyy h:mm a", new Locale("es", "ES"));

String formattedDateTime = date.format(dateTime);
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Yes I know, but the question description states `SimpleDateFormat` and the code snippet in the comment as well, so that's the one I used in the answer. Will update the answer with the `DateTimeFormatter`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

### JDBC 4.2 and java.time

```
    Locale desiredLanguage = Locale.forLanguageTag("es");
    DateTimeFormatter monthFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM", desiredLanguage);

    OffsetDateTime dateTime = yourResultSet.getObject("your_database_column", OffsetDateTime.class);
    String monthString = dateTime.format(monthFormatter);
```

Or to print in some particular time zone since the month doesn’t change at the same point in time in all time zones:

```
    ZonedDateTime zdt = dateTime.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid"));
    String monthString = zdt.format(monthFormatter);
```

### Avoid SimpleDateFormat

The `SimpleDateFormat` class that you referred to is notoriously trouvlesome and long outdated. Don’t use it. java.time, the modern Java date and time API, is so much nicer to work with.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.