# Different datetime format in Windows and Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows

I use this simple code to get dateTime pattern:

```
((SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.MEDIUM)).toPattern()
```

For US locale results for Linux and Windows are equal. And for RU / UK locales they are different!

US:
Windows: M/d/yy h:mm:ss a
Linux: M/d/yy, h:mm:ss a

UK:
Windows: dd/MM/**yy** HH:mm:ss
Linux: dd/MM/**y**, HH:mm:ss

RU:
Windows:dd.MM.**yy** H:mm:ss
Linux: dd.MM.**y**, H:mm:ss

What's the reason and what to do?

UPD: [SimpleDateFormat and locale based format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661325/simpledateformat-and-locale-based-format-string) has no answers to my question.
I need String pattern - and I can't get it using DateTimeFormater class.

Comment: `What's the reason?` - [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). Anyway you should look at [java8+ date/time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SimpleDateFormat and locale based format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661325/simpledateformat-and-locale-based-format-string)

Comment: So you suggest me to use java.time classes? But I need pattern as String. And I can't get string pattern from DateTimeFormatter.

Comment: You want [DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#getLocalizedDateTimePattern(java.time.format.FormatStyle,java.time.format.FormatStyle,java.time.chrono.Chronology,java.util.Locale)).

Comment: @VGR, thank you! It should be accepted answer! Can you write this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a pattern string, you can use [DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#getLocalizedDateTimePattern(java.time.format.FormatStyle,java.time.format.FormatStyle,java.time.chrono.Chronology,java.util.Locale)) to obtain it.  Be aware that DateTimeFormatter uses a slightly different set of pattern letters than SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Thank you!
Now I have equal pattern in Linux and Windows: dd.MM.y, H:mm:ss