# How to use Locale in LocalDateTime?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using this extension-function for getting day of week:

```
private fun WeatherList.getDayOfWeek() =
        LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(dt.toLong(), 0, ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate().dayOfWeek
```

dt - date time in my class in Unix

WeatherList is my class:

```
@Serializable
@Parcelize
data class WeatherList(
    val dt: Int,
    val main: Main,
    val weather: List<Weather>,
    val clouds: Clouds,
    val wind: Wind,
    val visibility: Int,
    val pop: Double,
    val sys: Sys,
    val dt_txt: String,
) : Parcelable
```

I was thinking that this should use Locale for output day of week but it's always English. So how to use locale language for day of week?

Comment: I would use a `ZonedDateTime` here, but that's something different. If you want to get the name of the day of week in a different locale, you can extract and translate it like this: `...dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.FRENCH);` for example.

Comment: @deHaar amazing. That's straigth what i was looking for. So i can use short day of week format by using TextStyle.SHORT and using my locale. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome... And by the way: A `LocalDateTime` already knows its day of week, so there's no need to call `toLocalDate()`.

Comment: @deHaar it's the same with toLocalTime(), right?

Comment: A `LocalDateTime` actually consists of a `LocalDate` and a `LocalTime`. An `OffsetDateTime` has a `ZoneOffset` in addition. I don't know if that answers your question, but it could...

Comment: @deHaar i meant if we can remove toLocaleDate() in my situation then if I want to use toLocaleTime() I can just not use it either

Comment: You can do `toLocalTime()` if you want to get the full `LocalTime` of a `LocalDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`, but if you want to get the hours of day you don't have to call `toLocalTime()` before, because a `LocalDateTime` has `getHour()` itself (in Java, maybe it's just `hour` in Kotlin). You can get the single units of time directly, you don't have to call anything in between.

Comment: @deHaar can you help me to handle with this function? I need to make it in SimpleDateFormat because LocalDateTime is min 26 sdk

Comment: You can use the [API Desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) or import the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) if you want to use (most part of) `java.time` in Android 26 and above.

Comment: @deHaar i need to use my extension on sdk 23 :( so i need it to be in SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Seriously, @SoulReaver313, don't use a `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`/`Calendar` anymore. Better import some library that enables `java.time` in lower API versions. But if you insist on using the old and outdated API, then have a look at questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661325/simpledateformat-and-locale-based-format-string). You will need to use the `E` abbreviation for day-of-week names.

Comment: @deHaar thank you. I'm already figured it out but i will definitely check libraries that you adviced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that takes a `Locale` and the epoch seconds as arguments and returns the name of the week as common in that specific `Locale`:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZoneOffset
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale

fun WeatherList.getDayOfWeekName(locale: Locale, epochSecs: Int): String {
    return LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(epochSecs.toLong(), 0, ZoneOffset.UTC)
                        .dayOfWeek
                        .getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, locale);
}
```

You can of course include a fixed `Locale` and directly reference some variable holding the epoch seconds, but especially the last line gives you the name of the day of week in the given `Locale`'s language and format.

Passing `Locale.GERMAN` and the epoch seconds `1631264387` would return `Freitag` (that's a *German* Friday).

Comment: Very good answer! **Comment for Java developers**: In Java, it would be `.getDayOfWeek()` 
 instead of `.dayOfWeek` as mentioned in this answer for Kotlin.